# jquery tr selector not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

```
    var row="<tr><td>"+segmentData.segmentName+"</td>" +
            "<td></td>"+
            "<td>"+segmentData.transTimelyTotal+"</td>"+
            "<td></td>"+
            "<td>"+segmentData.transUntimelyTotal+"</td>"+
            "<td></td>"+
            "<td>"+segmentData.transAmtTimelyTotal+"</td>"+
            "<td></td>"+
            "<td>"+segmentData.transAmtUntimelyTotal+"</td>"+
            "</tr>";
        var $row=$(row)

        var td = $("tr:nth-child(2)", $row);
```

I have above html row described in javascript and from there i am trying to get a td element at location third but it doesn't seem to be working as expected.

I am getting an undefined object, you can see the result below.

Any better way to get td element at location 2nd?

```
[prevObject: m.fn.init[1], context: undefined, selector: "tr:even"]
```

Comment: `$row.find("td:nth-child(2)");` try this

Comment: $row.find( "td:eq( 2 )" )  hope this works for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `nth-child` selector the wrong way.
`tr:nth-child` does not return the `tr`'s children, but instead returns the `tr` elements that are the nth-children of their respective parents.
What your selector should be

```
"tr td:nth-child(2)"
```

But since good HTML practices imply that `tr` elements should only contain `td` elements as the children, this selector would be enough:

```
"td:nth-child(2)"
```

Going back to your question, you asked the selector for the **2nd** `td` and not the **2nth** `td`. So, none of the above selectors are right. Here is what you should use:

```
"td:eq(2)"
```

Refer the spec for `nth-child` [here](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

Refer the spec for `eq` [here](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

$row.find("td:nth-child(2)"); worked